# Microsoft Exchange 2016 apply SSL certificates

Tags: ssl-certificate, exchange-server

Please I am trying to buy SSL certificate for my Exchange server 2016 deployment.

Where do I request and apply the SSL certificate, Edge Transport Server or Mailbox Server?

Can I apply the certificate on server, say Mailbox Role Server, then export it and apply it to the Edge Transport Role Server?

Also, should I request a wildcard certificate?

Answer (score 0):

For Microsoft Exchange 2016, [exchange server SSL certificates](https://www.clickssl.net/microsoft-exchange-server-ssl-certificates) remain the best. They are also know as UCC SSL. It works like multidomain certificate because secures multiple domains & sub domains with single certificate. So I don't think you need wildcard ssl.

This type of SSL certificate comes with Free unlimited Server Licensing. So You will have to first apply UCC (Exchange SSL) at Mailbox server. It will remain good if you reissue the same certificate for Edge Transport Role Server inplace of export it and apply it again for Edge Transport Role Server.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for your reply.  Let me see if I understand you right.  You mean I should buy a domain SSL certificate and apply it to the Mailbox server, then export it and apply it to the Edge Transport Server.  Or I don't need to apply it to Edge Transport Server.

Comment: You should buy exchange sever ssl and apply at Mailbox server. And reissue that same certificate and apply it to Edge Transport server.

Comment: Wow Dana, you are very knowledgeable.

Just one final question.

When creating the request for the certificate should I specify a "Wild_Card*"?

Comment: If you are go for exchange (UCC) SSL certificate then you don't need to specify wildcard (*) because it secures multiple domains (which you have specified in the certificate).

Comment: Many thanks Dana.  It took this long and I have been able to solve this problem.  The issue now is how to receive mails to and from the internet.  THis server is driving me up the wall.  I am considering Linux Red Hat.  Please help if you can before I migrate to Linux.